# Get a list of maibox databases in each DAG

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I have a need to get a list of databases contained in each DAG but I am struggling to get it. If I use

```
Get-databaseavailabilitygroup
```

I get a list of the DAGs and the member servers but as soon as I try

```
Get-databaseavailabilitygroup|get-mailboxdatabase
```

I get an error saying the DAG name can not be found on the DC.

What am I doing wrong?

We have 3 seperate environments each with different database names and a different number of databases. 
I am trying to get a list of the databases in each DAG as this will be passed into a function that works out which DAG to create the mail account on and then creates the account on the database with the least number of users on it.
I want to create it this way so I can use the same script across all environments and it will also cater for new databases

TIA

Andy

Answer (score 1):

That's what `Group-Object` is for:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase | 
Group-Object MasterServerOrAvailabilityGroup | 
Select -ExpandProperty Group
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out but would be interested in anything that is easier

```
$dags = get-databaseavailabilitygroup
foreach ($dag in $dags){
$mbx = Get-mailboxdatabase | Where-Object {$_.masterserveroravailabilitygroup -EQ $dag}
    foreach($db in $mbx){
        write-host $db.name
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((Get-MailboxServer) | Where-Object {$_.DatabaseAvailabilityGroup -eq 'EX13DAG'} | Select-Object -Property Name).Name
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.